# Joins with multiple tables/constraints OR has_one_through with secondary constraint

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I apologise for the contrived example

A `person` has ONE `journey` but is not directly connected to that `journey`, instead, they are connected via their `house` and `office`.

A `person belongs_to a house`, a `house has_many people`

A `person belongs_to a office`, a `office has_many people`

A `journey belongs_to a house`, a `house has many journeys`

A `journey belongs_to a office`, a `office has many journeys`

```
                         +---------+
       +---Belongs-To---->         <----Belongs-To--+
       |                 |  House  |                |
       |  +-Has-Many-----+         +-----Has-Many-+ |
       |  |              +---------+              | |
       |  |                                       | |
+------+--v+                                     +v-+--------+
|          |                                     |           |
|  Person  |                                     |  Journey  |
|          |                                     |           |
+------+--^+                                     +^-+--------+
       |  |                                       | |
       |  |              +----------+             | |
       |  +-Has-Many-----+          +----Has-Many-+ |
       |                 |  Office  |               |
       +----Belongs-To--->          <---Belongs-To--+
                         +----------+
```

Following that contrived example, what's the best way to allow the following:

```
person.journey
```

OR baring that a Join query with multiple tables (using ruby hashes) or using a `has_one_through` with extra table constraints.

We do have a sql query but we'd rather avoid using raw sql if we can, but it looks like this:

```
Person
.joins('INNER JOIN journeys
        ON journeys.office_id = person.office_id
        AND journeys.house_id = person.house_id')
```

Comment: A `person` belongs to an `office`, and `office` has many `journeys`. So, it looks to me that a `person` can have more than one `journeys`. It shouldn't be `person.journey`, but more like `person.journeys`. Even the association through `house` confirms this.

Comment: When done through either `office` or `house` you're right, but when done through both there's only one `journey` per `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I must use an answer to get more info.
Is it possible to have this case?

```
| Person                      |   | Journey                     |
|----+-----------+------------|   |----+-----------+------------|
| id | office_id | house_id   |   | id | office_id | house_id   |
|----+-----------+------------|   |----+-----------+------------|
| 1  | 1         | 1          |   | 1  | 1         | 1          |
| 2  | 1         | 1          |   | 2  | 1         | 1          |
| 3  | 1         | 1          |   | 3  | 1         | 1          |
| 4  | 1         | 1          |   | 4  | 1         | 1          |
```

How can you find the journey of a specific person on the data of this case?

If you consider `person = Person.find(1)` and use `person.office_id` and `person.house_id` as keys to look up in the table Journey, you will fetch ids 1,2,3 and 4. Not just one journey.

Following your replies, this case never happens because validation filters doe not allow.
So, what's required is to access the Journey table with a double foreign key: `office_id` and `house_id`.

The best solution would be

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  belongs_to :house

  has_one :journey, foreign_keys: [:house_id, :office_id]

end
```

but multiple foreign key is not yet supported by rails.

One possible workaround could be defining the instance method `journey` for the `Person` class:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  belongs_to :house

  def journey
    Journey.where(office_id: office_id, house_id: house_id).last
  end

end
```

So you can call `person.journey`.

Comment: A `person` has one `journey` becuase a `person` and `journey` can only have both one `office_id` and `house_id` each,  by matching a `person` to a `journey` by the `office_id` and `house_id` that they both share, you can match a  `journey` to a `person`.

Comment: I'll rename the examples if it helps but in this case a person and journey can never be assigned to a office or house more then once, I realise this is a contrived example (as I said) but this is how this particular system is designed.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.. But if you look at my case: **-1-** no person has more than one office; **-2-** no person has more than one house; **-3-** no journey has more than one office; **-4-** no journey has more than one house. How can you find the journey of a specific person the data of my case? (I edited my post).

Comment: That case will never happen, there is a uniqueness validation, I did say this is a contrived example but the basics are the same, I guess I should have used other words for the example.

Comment: Well, if you want to paste my the tables to your original post, changing the `office_id` and `house_id` values according to possible real data and also adding the expected result of the query, maybe somebody or myself can try to help ;)

Comment: Edited with a possible solution. Sorry if I've been stubborn, but I had to settle my mind.